# Deploy image from directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have referred this tutorial to create deployable image:

https://medium.com/@javatechie/kubernetes-tutorial-run-deploy-spring-boot-application-in-k8s-cluster-using-yaml-configuration-3b079154d232

I want to use this HELM chart in order to deploy image from directory:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-k8s
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-boot-k8s
  replicas: 2 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-boot-k8s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-boot-k8s
          image: springboot-k8s-example:1.0 
# Image that will be used to containers in the cluster
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080 
# The port that the container is running on in the cluster
```

How I can deploy the docker image `springboot-k8s-example:1.0` from a directory or from a private Docker registry from url link?

Comment: Are you using some other users's docker registry ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you will need to create an image pull secret to pull an image from your own repository. I have reproduced your issue and pushed the image to my privet docker registry and then pulled the image successfully.

This could be done by using the below command here I am assuming that you are using docker privet registry :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=<docker-username> --docker-password=<your-password> --docker-email=<docker-email
```

This will create a secret and now you will need to add it in your deployment manifest so that it could authenticate with privet registry to pull the image.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-k8s
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-boot-k8s
  replicas: 2 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-boot-k8s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-boot-k8s
          image: sidharthpai/springboot-k8s-example:1.0
# Image that will be used to containers in the cluster
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

For more reference to create image pull secret : [image pull secret](https://github.com/javahometech/kubernetes/tree/master/secrets)

Now to prepare the helm chart you will need to create a chart with relevant name and then configure Deployment.yml & Secret.yml in the helm chart template.Once this is done you will need to configure values.yml.

Deployment.yml (template)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name}}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.app}}
  replicas: 2 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.app}}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.name}}
          image: {{ .Values.image}}
# Image that will be used to containers in the cluster
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{ .Values.secret_name}}
```

Secret.yml(Template)

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ .Values.docker_config}}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secret_name}}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Values.yml

```
name: spring-boot-k8s
app: spring-boot-k8s
image: sidharthpai/springboot-k8s-example:1.0
secret_name: regcred
docker_config: <docker-config-value>
```

[image: Deployed the application using helm chart]